# Lower bound for the maximal complete subgraphs with all edges of the same color, for a complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Consider the complete graph on $n$ vertices, and all possible graphs that can be obtained from it by coloring its edges with exactly $n$ colors. Given one of these colored graphs, we can determine the maximum size of a complete (maximal) subgraph of it with all its edges of the same color.

I would like to get a lower bound for the size of the maximal subgraphs, as described above, over all possible colorings of the complete graph on $n$ vertices.

Any hint or result about this?

Comment: Seriously, the number of vertices and the number of colors are both equal to $n$? That wasn't a typo? In that case there is no guarantee of having a monochromatic complete subgraph with more than two vertices.

Comment: Call the vertices $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$. For $i\lt j$ color the edge $v_iv_j$ with color $i$. So the edges of the complete graph on $n$ vertices are colored with $n-1$ colors, and there is no monochromatic triangle.If $n\gt2$ you can easily modify this coloring so that it uses exactly $n$ colors.

Comment: Thank you @bof I didn't think about it carefully.

Comment: The edges of a complete graph on $2k$ vertices can be colored with $2k-1$ colors so that no two edges of the same color have a common vertex.